# Is there a way to delete from pushgateway using a metric/label value?

Tags: prometheus, prometheus-pushgateway

I only see how to delete from pushgateway using 'curl -X DELETE http://localhost:9091/metrics/job/some_job/instance/some_instance', but I want to delete metrics that contain a specific label value, how would I do that?

**UPDATE:**
I was using python to write the script, and prometheus has a Client for python with a function 'delete_from_pushgateway()'

This can be found at: https://github.com/prometheus/client_python

Answer (score 0):

according to [Prometheus Gateway README](https://github.com/prometheus/pushgateway/blob/master/README.md)

- Delete all metrics in the group identified by {job="some_job",instance="some_instance"}:

  curl -X DELETE http://pushgateway.example.org:9091/metrics/job/some_job/instance/some_instance
- Delete all metrics in the group identified by {job="some_job"} (note that this does not include metrics in the {job="some_job",instance="some_instance"} group from the previous example, even if those metrics have the same job label):

  curl -X DELETE http://pushgateway.example.org:9091/metrics/job/some_job